# Is explorer.cardano.org down?

Tags: blockchain-explorer

I was wondering if explorer.cardano.org was down.

The explorer page keeps displaying a charging icon.

[image: cardano explorer charging page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks like it is.

```
$ curl https://explorer.cardano.org/graphql
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

You might want to use an alternative explorer, such as [cexplorer.io](https://cexplorer.io/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know why it is down or when will it be up again ?

Comment: Not sure, but I have pinged IOG to see.

Comment: Thanks, where have you reached them ?

Comment: The best place is the IOG discord technical chat.